# hold all binded events of a html element for a specific time with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to hold all binded events of a HTML element for a specific time with Jquery?
Example- i want to hold events of a button while my listing is loading so that no body can click on this button, i don't want to disable or hide this button.

Comment: did you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var stime = +(new Date()),
    delay = 5000000; // add events 5secs after

var element = document.getElementById('mybutton');

var checker = function() {
 var ctx = setInterval(function() {
   if ((+ new Date() >= stime + delay)
   {
     element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('you fire me');
     });
     clearInterval(ctx);
     return ;
   }
 }, 250);
}();
```